# HTML+CSS: How do I put this 2 buttons at the same level vertically

Tags: html, css

I want to align those two buttons (Login and Registrar) at the same level but as they are different forms "Registrar" button is being placed on the "next line".

Here is the issue, visually:
[image]

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<section class="header_form_login">
    <form action="index2.html" method="GET">
        <label for="user">Usuario:<br></label>
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user_input">
        <label for="pass"><br>Contraseña:<br></label>
        <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass">
        <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login">
    </form>
    <form action="registro.html" method="GET">
        <input type="submit" id="register" value="Registrar">
    </form>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
header > section.header_form_login{
    font-weight: 500;
    align-items: right;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

header > section.header_form_login > form > input#user{
    width: 200px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

header > section.header_form_login > form > input#pass{
    width: 200px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

    /* BUTTONS */
    header > section.header_form_login > form > input#login{
        border: none;
        background-color: #CAB99F;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-size: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    header > section.header_form_login > form > input#register{
        border: none;
        background-color: #CAB99F;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-size: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

Thanks a lot!!!

PD: Feel free to give me recommendations, I'm kinda new to html and css coding.

I need help with html and css, specifically, with buttons being placed at the same level vertically but from different forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Refactored `CSS` to share styles.

I would restructure your `HTML` and fix your `CSS` to get things working properly. Also, when using `id`s, they are meant to be unique, so there's no need for a long lookup query such as:

```css
header > section.header_form_login > form > input#login { … }
```

Just use

```css
#login { … }
```

To make the "`button`s" align, I made the register `input` a link. This is pretty standard. Then I added some `CSS` to align these elements on the same line.

```css
.form-buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Here is how I could restructure your markup and styles.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header_form_login {
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 250px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#user,
#pass {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

/* BUTTONS */

#login,
#register {
  border: none;
  background-color: #CAB99F;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 15px;  
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;  
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;  
}

#login {
  margin-right: 2.5px;  
}

#register {
  margin-left: 2.5px;
}

.form-buttons {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<section class="header_form_login">
  <form action="index2.html" method="GET">
    <label for="user">Usuario:<br></label>
    <input type="text" id="user" name="user_input">
    <label for="pass">Contraseña:</label>
    <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass">
    <div class="form-buttons">
      <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login">
      <a href="registro.html" id="register">Register</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4rf1yLhj/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't generally like there being two forms in the same place to drive 2 actions. Assuming that you don't need username and password sending to your register page, then I would implement as follows:

```
<section class="header_form_login">
    <form action="index2.html" method="GET">
        <label for="user">Usuario:<br></label>
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user_input">
        <label for="pass"><br>Contraseña:<br></label>
        <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass">
        <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login">
        <a href="registro.html" id="register" title="Registrar">Registrar</a>
    </form>
</section>
```

CSS for Buttons:

```
/* BUTTONS */
header > section.header_form_login > form > input#login{
    border: none;
    background-color: #CAB99F;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

header > section.header_form_login > form > input#register{
    border: none;
    background-color: #CAB99F;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I was doing it this way at the same time you responded, thanks! :) The problem is, can you still put this "Register" button right next to the other one instead under it?

Comment: I just did it making them display: flex and one on right and the other left. Thanks for the help!